# When you register a sidebar in Wordpress, is it possible to choose in what order it appears in the admin

Tags: widgets

I've registered some new sidebars. They are appearing on appearance->widgets screen. However, they appear in two columns and the order is arbituary. Is there a way to config the order and columns in the widget admin screen?

Comment: Interesting. I think they appear in the order they are registered, no way to declare the order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sidebars are output in registration order, which is implicitly captured by how they are added to a `$wp_registered_sidebars` global.

This can easily be manipulated, for example following code will move `first` sidebar to the start:

```
add_action( 'register_sidebar', function ( $sidebar ) {

    global $wp_registered_sidebars;

    if ( 'first' === $sidebar['id'] ) {
        $sidebar = $wp_registered_sidebars['first'];
        unset( $wp_registered_sidebars['first'] );
        $wp_registered_sidebars = [ 'first' => $sidebar ] + $wp_registered_sidebars;
    }
} );

register_sidebar( [ 'name' => 'one', 'id' => 'one' ] );
register_sidebar( [ 'name' => 'two', 'id' => 'two' ] );
register_sidebar( [ 'name' => 'first', 'id' => 'first' ] );
```

Comment: can we use `admin_init` hook to reorder widget area appearance, because if we hook on `register_sidebar` it will be execute each time when side bar registered. https://gist.github.com/ravinderk/40f18459563de9bdbc65

Comment: Depends on what exactly you want and when registrations run. That's pretty early.